# How can I use client certificates for Graph authentification with TokenAcquirerFactory inside of a console application?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I've used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-console-app-netcore-acquire-token#application-initialization) official guide to build an console application which runs as a daemon client and automatically acquirers an Graph AccessToken using the credentials provided in `appsettings.json`. My console app must also modify `DistributionLists` and as you can [only modify them using the ExchangeOnlineManagement PowerShell Module](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-intune/graph-add-remove-user-to-distribution-list/m-p/2922065) . I use the C# `PowerShell` package to call these functions.

For the ExchangeOnline part I can easily use a client certificate:

```cs
using var ps = PowerShell.Create(runspace);

ps.AddCommand("Connect-ExchangeOnline");
ps.AddParameters(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["Organization"] = azureDomain,
    ["CertificateThumbprint"] = certThumbprint,
    ["AppID"] = clientId
});
```

Now I would like to configure my `appsettings.json` that `TokenAcquirerFactory` also uses a certificate.
Currently my `appsettings.json` follows this schema:

```js
{
    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "TenantId": "[Enter here the tenantID or domain name for your Azure AD tenant]",
        "ClientId": "[Enter here the ClientId for your application]",
        "ClientCredentials": [
            {
                "SourceType": "ClientSecret",
                "ClientSecret": "[Enter here a client secret for your application]"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

which needs an `ClientSecret`.

I want to use certificate authentification for my daemon app, because then I could use the certificate, which is already configured in the azure portal for the `ExchangeOnline` part, for my deamon app too. So I would just need to reset one certificate every year, instead of one certificate and one token.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Edit: You can find a project which is using the `SecretToken`, as I currently do, [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph).

Comment: You need to make two HTTP Request from client to server as shown in the picture on your last link.  The first request gets the token and the second request does a query where the token is sent with the request.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Yes I know how to make the requests, but how can I tell `TokenAcquirerFactory` that it should use a client certificate to get the AccessToken? I don't want to use a ClientSecret.

Comment: The json config file you can add any properties you want.  Then you read the properties in the console app.  What you want is a app code to call TokenAquireFactory with the correct parameters.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore

Comment: Thanks, your second link helped me, there were some very helpful references on the site, now I have finally managed to find a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay with the help of @jdweng and a lot of trial and error I was able to come up with this config scheme which works now:

```
{
    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "TenantId": "[Enter here the tenantID or domain name for your Azure AD tenant]",
        "ClientId": "[Enter here the ClientId for your application]",
        "ClientCredentials": [
            {
                "SourceType": "StoreWithThumbprint",
                "CertificateStorePath": "LocalMachine/Root",
                "CertificateThumbprint": "<My Thumbprint>"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now `TokenAcquirerFactory` uses the installed certificate with the thumbprint specified in the `appsettings.json` to get the AccessToken and `GraphServiceClient` from the Graph API.

If you are now using a `TokenAcquirerFactory`

```cs
var tokenAcquirerFactory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance();
tokenAcquirerFactory.Services.AddMicrosoftGraph();
ServiceProvider = tokenAcquirerFactory.Build();
```

you can simply make API calls by using the `ServiceProvider`:

```cs
var graphClient = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<GraphServiceClient>();
var me = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();
```

I found the main parts for my config [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/3-Using-KeyVault) and [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Using-certificates).